# Ubuntu not loading GUI because of NVIDIA?

Tags: 20.04, nvidia

I recently encountered an issue where my operating system freezes during boot-up, displaying a specific screen. Could this be related to an NVIDIA issue?

[image]

Comment: Did you recently change the Secure Boot setting in your BIOS, by chance, or update the Nvidia drivers? Does Ubuntu boot if you disable Secure Boot?

Comment: Hello @johnandmegh, 
I switch on this pc after a long time and this was the situation. 
I have been able to enter in the recovery mode, and run an upgrade of the packages and fixing dependencies. It works again now.
thank you for your time